# Can providing phpinfo() result to SO make security break of my server?

Tags: php, security

Sometimes troubleshooting the php configuration problem needs to know the output of `phpinfo()`. But, as it provide server internal configuration it may be break security of a server, if someone use this output as hacking.

If the above thinking is true then what can one do when post a question about php configuration in SO?

Comment: Do not post sensitive information and direct links to your site. Use http://example.com as URL. Remove all passwords/tokens/etc, replacing them with fake ones or starts "*"

Comment: Presumably that would only help with known exploits which depend on specific configuration settings, and presumably these kinds of exploits would be discoverable with or without seeing an info dump. `phpinfo` doesn't typically contain any *secrets* (passwords etc.). But either way, the entire dump is ginormous, so you should first and foremost *understand* roughly what's what and only post the relevant snippets, optionally redacted as necessary.